# How to use drag and drop across frames in Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

I tried to drag to drop an element from a frame to a non-frame.
I know this is a repetitive question in StackOverflow, but I did not get any correct answer for the same question. Requesting your help on the same.

**Code used:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
public class DragDropIframes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.msn.com/en-in/");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("adcontainer")));
        WebElement drag = driver.findElement(By.className("adcontainer"));
        WebElement drop = driver.findElement(By.id("q"));
        System.out.println("cde");
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        Actions a1 = new Actions(driver);
        Actions a2 = a1.clickAndHold(drag);
        a1.build();
        a2.perform();
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        Actions a3 =a1.moveToElement(drop).release(drop);
        a3.perform();
    }
}
```

**Error message:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: UnknownError: Cannot release a button when no button is pressed.'UnknownError: Cannot release a button when no button is pressed.' when calling method: [wdIMouse:: up]
Command duration or timeout: 343 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenese is a flavour of Javascript which has a "Same Origin Policy" security restriction. If your frames are from different websites, dragging/dropping between the two would violate the Same Origin Policy and not be allowed.

One answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858214/how-selnium-webdriver-overcomes-same-origin-policy).

If you're not married to Selenium, another way to sidestep the Same Origin Policy restriction is to use Sikuli. Sikuli is an open-source java-based cross-platform record/playback tool that uses object recognition instead of object names. If you can see it on the screen, you can automate it. It's not a magic pill that will solve all your automation problems, but it might be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

> another way to sidestep the Same Origin Policy restriction is to use Sikuli.

Another object recognition based solution is to use the free Kantu [Visual Testing](https://a9t9.com/kantu/web-testing) app. It works just like Sikuli, but inside a Chromium web browser. Since it works "inside" Chromium, you can run many tests at once, and run it headless.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the structure of frames, one can always use Robot class to drag and drop elements across them. I am providing a sample code just in case:

```
//Setting up chrome driver
WebDriverManager.getInstance(CHROME).setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();

//Redirecting to the website
driver.get("website_url");

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(x-coordinate1, y-coordinate1);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

Thread.sleep(2000);
robot.mouseMove(x-coordinate2, y-coordinate2);

Thread.sleep(2000);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
```